# Can we get rid of the absolute value on this case?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, absolute-value

I have a small misunderstanding about the correct solution of a differential equation. In fact, my problem is more about understanding the form of the solution rather than the equation itself.

Say we have : $I \subset R$ and $I$ is an open interval of $R$ with $0$ not included in $I$.
We obtain a solution that is :

$$ \lambda \frac{e^{x}}{|x|} $$

It is said that we can write directly the solution without the absolute value because we can write either $\lambda$ or $-\lambda$ then : the general solution is :

$$ \lambda \frac{e^{x}}{x} $$

I don't understand this simplification as, in my understanding, $\lambda$ and $-\lambda$ are 2 distinct values, therefore we should still have :

if $x>0$ then $\lambda \frac{e^{x}}{x}$
else : $-\lambda \frac{e^{x}}{x}$

Could you explain why the general solution get rid of the minus here ?

Thank you,

Comment: The simplification is valid because $x\in I$ has always the same sign, and $\lambda$ is an arbitrary constant. Thus, the solution $\lambda e^x/|x|$ is either always $\lambda e^x/x$ or always $-\lambda e^x/x$, and for the latter you can replace $-\lambda$ with $\lambda'$, another arbitrary constant, *without loss of generality*.

Comment: Thank you @Jean-ClaudeArbaut : it is very silly but I am still confused. I know that the solution is always a : constant*$e^{x}/x$ but in my view : it's not always the same constant before and after 0... As you wrote it : we have $\lambda$ and $\lambda '$ ... Thank you again

Comment: The interval doesn't contain $0$, therefore there is no *before and after $0$*, you are always on the same side. That's why you can do this. Otherwise, for any $\lambda$, $x$ could take positive and negative values, and you couldn't get rid of the minus sign.

Comment: The expression before and after $0$ gives two unrelated solutions over two disjoint domains.